# POST body not sent / received

Tags: javascript, php, http, post, react-native

I'm making an app with React Native and I'm struggling with a server problem. I made some HTTP requests without any body and it's all working, but now I'm trying to make a POST and it's working like a charm in Postman (request runner tool) but not when it's in the code:

[image]

So in my PHP I'm returning POST data that I sent in the body, and it's working here, but in my code it's returning null and my SQL is not executed:

```
save()
{
    this.updateDatabase(this.state.data).then((response) => {
        console.warn("id: " + response.id + "  status: " + response.status);
    });
}

async updateDatabase(newData)
{
    const response = await fetch('http://XXX.XXX.XXX:8888/updateApplication.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            data: newData,
        })
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
}
```

And here is my PHP:

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
    $data = json_decode($json)->{'data'};

    $appRequest = "UPDATE app_forms SET status = '".$data->{'status'}."'WHERE id = '".$data->{'id'}."'";

    $appResults = $connection->query($appRequest);

    $response = array ('id'=>$data->{'id'},'status'=>$data->{'status'});
    echo json_encode($response);
```

I don't understand why it won't work in my code...
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: can you `var_dump($json)`, and try to see whats received in through request

Comment: I got the same error as the answer of @tre below, and when I replace content type it's still null

Comment: Which `Content-Type` do you plan to use? `multipart/form-data` or `application/json`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrong format in body.
Try this:

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( {data: newData } );
```

Then update request:

```
mode: 'no-cors',
body: data
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm getting a "multipart != application/json" error and I tried to replace content type with "multipart/form-data" as I saw on internet but it's still null

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I did not pay attention. I think answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/4957195

Getting data from post JSON.

Postman sends form data, but your fetch script sends raw json

Comment: I can't get something displayed when using the 'php://input'... It's just blank